# Ford transit though was going to blow

Tags: ford, turbocharger, transit

Yesterday I was coming on the highway with a Ford Transit and suddenly I noticed that the power was not normal and thought I had a flat tyre. As I turn to the petrol station lost all the power and a dreadful noise started with a lot of smoke.I immediately tried to turn it off - but even off the noise and the smoke continued - I thought it was going to explode! Sundelly all stoped. The towing service man thinks it was the turbo.....can you help?

Comment: turbo seal possibly among several issues - have you checked the oil level?

Comment: please add more information like coolant level-did your car overheat-oil level is it low-can you see any leaks-any ruptured hoses-have any hoses come loose-did the smoke come from the engine or the tailpipe-color of the smoke black-white-gray.

Answer (score 2):

Did the engine continue to run for a while after you turned it off? This could be a seal gone allowing engine oil to get sucked into the turbo. If this is the case you are lucky it stopped, they can sometime run on until the engine blows or the oil is all burnt and it seizes. I wouldn't start it again until it's fixed.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: it is good advice to not start the car until the cause is known.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to you all for being so cooperative!
I think that what happened was a busted turbo, that allowed oil into the engine at a high pressure.
This caused that dreadful high rev until it literally died in my hands...
The smoke was obviously white and everyone thought the engine was going to burst in flames. We had two long time drivers in the car and we were both focused on the ignition key and on and eventually stacked accelerator, but nobody thought about stalling the engine with the 5th gear and clutch!
How could I be so dumb?
Regards
Rod